# Fonts in openGL

Tags: fonts

I'm fairly new at c++ and I'm trying to make my own font drawing function As such, I have a font class which contains lots of Image objects like this:

```
  Image A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
  Image a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
  Image n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9;
```

I'll be populating the character images from a single large image file, and drawing them as needed onto quads. Now, the obvious solution would be to just keep all this in a map. However, I'm concerned about performance issues having to iterate through that entire map in search of the correct letter for every character on display for every single frame.

Is there any shortcut here, or is that all there is to it?

Note, I know there are probably tons of free and open source opengl text drawing libraries out there, but I'm doing this for practice as much as anything else. I'm interested in an efficient solution to my current problem, not necessarily a better but different solution altogether. Unless my approach is somehow fundamentally wrong, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you find yourself writing 62 identical variable definitions should be a strong hint that you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Character codes make perfectly good array indexes. Or, at least they did when ASCII was the only character set and the maximum value would be 255. In these days of Unicode you need to be a bit more careful about the range you allocate, but from your sample code you're not interested in anything except alphanumerics anyway.

Since you're doing this as a learning exercise, after converting to an array, think about putting all the character shapes in a single Image (sometimes called a strike) and just storing the pixel coordinates for each character, not an entire image.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I had already figured as much. I'd forgotten all about the ASCII stuff, but recalled it going through this tutorial: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/330742-quick-tutorial-variable-width-bitmap-fonts/ I've since implemented something similar to that, though I still store a copy of small images( taken from a larger one) inside my character structure; it just seemed more performance-efficient to me when passing it along to my opengl drawing functions, and the only downside I can see is that it possibly takes some more memory than keeping them all inside one picture and longer loading.

Comment: As long as it's ASCII I don't even need to search for the characters, I can just take it straight from the string into the array and get the data. And the Bitmap Font Generator application really seems to make it easy to use any font I desire.